# AngularJS not sending dynamic data while data toggle="buttons" is in div class

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on an app and I am trying to send a radio button with a specific value back to the server. I console logged out the value before inserting in the data-toggle="buttons" and I was able to view the value of price.label. Although, as soon as I place the data-toggle="buttons" in the view, the console log becomes null.

```
<div class="form-group">    
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg {{price.color}}" ng-repeat="price in shares.prices">
    <input type="radio"  name="report" ng-model="item.report_pricing" value="{{price.value}}"> {{price.label}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how I can get around this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `won't send my dynamic` what? and send where?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I am trying to send price.value to the server. I console logged out the value before inserting the data-toggle buttons and I was able to retrieve the correct value but once I put in data-toggle buttons it became null.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known problems when using bootstrap together with AngularJs, specifically when you try to bring in the Bootstrap JavaScript components into an Angular project.

There are several UI bootstrap modules that make bootstrap and AngularJs usages seamless via directives. They already solve these type of problems for you.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

**You can add ui-boostrap module to your angular app by doing the following...**

```
<script src="../angular-bootstrap/0.8.0/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

**Inject a module into your AngularJS application the following way...**

```
(function() {
        'use strict';

        /* App Module */

        angular.module('myApp', [
            'myApp.core'
            'myApp.services',
            'myApp.directives'
        ]);

    })();




(function() {
        'use strict';

        angular.module('myApp.core', [
            /*
             * Angular modules
             */
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngRoute',
            'ngSanitize',
            /*
             * Our reusable cross app code modules
             */
            'blocks.exception',
            'blocks.logger',
            'blocks.router',
            'myApp.services',
            'myApp.directives',
            /*
             * 3rd Party modules
             */
            'ui.bootstrap'
        ]);
    })();
```

**Then just simply use the ui-module tags. Examples here....**
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have tried the above code but the btn-radio="''" doesnt want to work with dynamic data? Do you know anyways around this?

Comment: I updated the answer with steps on how to add ui-bootstrap to your angularJS app

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, i ended up using for my problem. Since I was unable to use data-toggle, I used Angular UI Bootstrap - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I was also unable to use a dynamic value for btn-radio so I removed out the ng-repeat and hand-typed in the value. Although, I was able to make everything else dynamic. This ended up working perfectly for my problem. May not work for people with a really large btn-group.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-gray btn-lg withoutpricing-gray" ng-model="item.report_pricing" btn-radio="'none'">{{prices.0.label}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-gray btn-lg renter-blue" ng-model="item.report_pricing" btn-radio="'renter'">{{prices.1.label}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-gray btn-lg owner-purple" ng-model="item.report_pricing" btn-radio="'owner'">{{prices.2.label}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-gray btn-lg combined-orange" ng-model="item.report_pricing" btn-radio="'both'">{{prices.3.label}}</label>
</div>
```